# Google docs, remember last position

Tags: google-drive

I use Google Docs a lot for text editing. The difficulty I am facing is that I have documents with 100s of pages; and each time I open a document, it opens with the cursor on top of the first page. I wonder if Google Docs can remember the last position when the document was last closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a bookmark (insert -> bookmark). Then you can add #name_of_bookmark to the end of the url.

eg: http://docs.google.com/document/d/15xm3Bx4Elnjbg0VNY#name_of_bookmark

This is the only solution to your problem, Google Docs does not remembers last position of the cursor or anything lik that.